# Problem with navigationView, listview and item selected

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my android sample app. I have a NavigationView with ListView menu. I cant mark the item selected as selected. I tried with setItemChecked but nothing :(

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

 private DrawerLayout dl;
 private ActionBarDrawerToggle t;
 private NavigationView nv;
 private ListView listview;
 private List < String > markets;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  dl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
  listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
  t = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.string.Open, R.string.Close);

  dl.addDrawerListener(t);
  t.syncState();

  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

  getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
  markets = new ArrayList < String > ();
  markets.add("Sample");

  ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, markets);
  listview.setAdapter(adapter);
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  nv = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  if (t.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) return true;
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {

  Fragment fragment = null;
  Class fragmentClass = null;
  if (position == 0) fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
  else fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
  try {
   fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

  // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
  setTitle(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
  dl.closeDrawers();
 }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `NavigationView`'s built-in menu, which you can just set a `checkableBehavior` on, instead of sticking a `ListView` in it? That's really not how `NavigationView` is meant to be used.

Comment: Because i have a dynamic menu

Comment: You can add, remove, and modify items in a `NavigationView`'s menu.

Comment: i used navigationView as u suggested but now i have problem when i click on an item no effect happens. `menu = nv.getMenu();
        SubMenu menuGroup = menu.addSubMenu("My menu group");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Option1").setShortcut('3', 'c');`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what menu design you're trying to achieve with that, but a submenu is not the same as a group. You need to specify a group ID in the `add()` call for a group that has your `checkableBehavior` on it. Also, IIRC, you'll need to call `setCheckable(true)` on each item you add. Gimme a second, and I'll put together a quick test.

Comment: Yeah, just make sure you're adding those items to the same group, the group has the `android:checkableBehavior="single"`, and you're calling `setCheckable(true)` on each item. Here's my quick test: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11M6pW1S7jR63bsO6OBu_n1pQqwIdZ0du/view?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: I love you <3 Thank you for your answer and patience